# Linux kernel thread serialization

Tags: linux, multithreading, serialization, linux-kernel

I'm writing linux kernel module (it is LSM). 
It is easy to make hooks in several linux kernel operations but I'm wondering how they are called from multiple threads(and processes).

I'm going to use shared data that may be read/written from multiple threads.
Is there any rule how we should lock the shared data?

If the LSM hook calls are serialized outside, we don't need to lock the shared data, but I couldn't find any documents that specifically says about this.

I also want to know the same thing for procfs or securityfs interface operations.
Are they serialized outside?

My guess it that they are NOT serialized because no docs says so. But still not sure.

Comment: Standard Linux approach is to use mutexes to control access to shared data.